# Glassfish no response on HTTPS after installing SSL-certificates

Tags: java, ssl, https, glassfish, ssl-certificate

Following several tutorials I've installed my SSL-certificates like so:

**Step 1. Import the keystore with key and CSR**

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /root/cert/keystore.jks -destkeystore /usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks
```

**Step 2. Import the root, intermediates and signed certificate**

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore /usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks -alias root -file /root/cert/Equifax.crt
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore /usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks -alias intermediate1 -file /root/cert/RapidSSL_Primary_Intermediate.crt
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore /usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks -alias intermediate2 -file /root/cert/RapidSSL_Secondary_Intermediate.crt
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore /usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks -alias mydomain_com -file /root/cert/mydomain_com.crt
```

**3. Renaming all `s1as` references to `mydomain_com` in domain.xml**

**4. Restart the domain**

```
/usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/bin/asadmin restart-domain domain1
```

My certificate chain properly states a length of `4`. The `alias` is matching with the CSR, import of signed certificate and the value in `domain.xml`.

However, when visiting `https://mydomain.com` I get no response while it worked fine with the default self signed certificate `s1as`. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the passphrase for your imported key the same as the master passphrase of the glassfish server?

The server needs the same passphrase as master passphrase, for the keystore and for the key. So check that all three passphrases are the same.

Comment: Oh my imported key has indeed another password, will try changing the master password! Will let you know how it turns out, thanks in advance.

Comment: I know my master password, however `/usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/bin/asadmin change-master-password domain1` directly states `Incorrect current master password. You will not be able to change it.`. I don't even get a chance to type the correct password, is there any way to do so?

Comment: @Aquillo Never changed the master password therefore I can't help on this topic. Perhaps the easiest in the first place could be to change the password of your key with `keytool -keypasswd`.

Comment: Ok, thanks so far. At least I know where the issue is. Will try to set this password accordingly and if it helps I will accept your answer.

Comment: I have this exact problem on GlassFish 3.1.2.2 with all passwords matching.